# Simple MYSQL query sum issue when using left join

Tags: mysql, left-join

My challenge is as follows: I have a very simple SQL query that takes values from two different tables, including the SUM values.

Table 1 (`treatments`) is as follows:

```
MedicineDescription     |     InitAmount | Cost
Mybulen                 |     90         | 194
```

Table 2 (`treatmentrecords`) is as follows:

```
Treatment    |     AmountGiven
Mybulen      |     60
```

My SQL query:

```
SELECT t.MedicineDescription
     , SUM(t.initAMount) startAmount
     , SUM(r.AmountGiven) endAmount
     , SUM(t.Cost) tCost
  FROM treatments t
  LEFT 
  JOIN treatmentrecords r
    ON r.Treatment = t.MedicineDescription
GROUP 
    BY MedicineDescription
```

and finally... the results:

```
MedicineDescription | StartAmount | EndAmount | tCost
Mybulen             |   90        | 180.00    | 194
```

As you can see both the start amount and tcost is calculating perfectly, the issue is only that the SUM returned for EndAmount is not correct.

Any ideas will be appreciated!

Comment: I cannot replicate this result. See https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/333952/why-should-i-provide-an-mcve-for-what-seems-to-me-to-be-a-very-simple-sql-query

Comment: Add a count(*) to show how many records the select has found.

Comment: Check this http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/304ec4/1

Comment: Able to get expected result with the same set of data... Check the number of records in 'treatmentrecords' table

Comment: SUM(t.initAMount) startAmount should be t.InitAmount i guess as per your table

Comment: Just like the others I can't replicate the problem which suggest you might have different data, what would select AmountGiven from treatmentrecords where Treatment = 'Mybulen'; return?      http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/5320f7/6

Comment: I also cannot replicate the issue on Fiddle. The data above was truncated from 300-odd rows. Somehow a more specific LEFT JOIN statement did the trick. Waiting for more info on Samar's answer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem with your query is in the `Group` clause, you  are grouping according to a field in the first table. Therefore, you didn't have the wanted result form the 2nd table. try this query

```
SELECT t.MedicineDescription
     , SUM(t.initAMount) startAmount
     , r.sumAmountGiven endAmount
     , SUM(t.Cost) tCost
  FROM treatments t
  INNER JOIN (
     SELECT Treatment
         , SUM(AmountGiven) AS sumAmountGiven
     FROM treatmentrecords
     GROUP BY Treatment
  ) AS r ON r.Treatment = t.MedicineDescription
   GROUP BY MedicineDescription
```

here I've add a sub query, I've named it `r` to follow your old name. This query returns a relation that have two columns a `treatment` column and a `sum(AmountGiven)`. The sum here grouped with according to the `treatment` column. After that the join adds the sum column to the main query.

Comment: I'll be studying this answer carefully as it somehow works. Please, can you explain why the elaborate join?

Comment: I'll add some info in a minute